# Context initialization failed. File not found [javax/persistence/Entity.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i am new to spring and hibernate. i am creating a dummy application and getting this exception. i searched a lot for this but didn't find solution for this. plz help me

```
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: com.sm.entity.User; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [javax/persistence/Entity.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:267)
```

And here is my contextApplication.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sm.controller, com.sm.dao, com.sm.entity, com.sm.model, com.sm.service"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="file:D:\workspace\SM\src\main\resources\System.property"/>

    <!--<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">

        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                &lt;!&ndash;<value>file:D:\admins\new\m-POS_Merchant_Portal\opt\estel\mpos\mPOSMerchantPortal\conf\messages</value>&ndash;&gt;
                &lt;!&ndash;<value>file:D:\admins\new\m-POS_Merchant_Portal\opt\estel\mpos\mPOSMerchantPortal\conf\system</value>&ndash;&gt;

                <value>file:D:\Estel\m-POS_Merchant_Portal\opt\estel\mpos\mPOSMerchantPortal\conf\messages</value>
                <value>file:D:\Estel\m-POS_Merchant_Portal\opt\estel\mpos\mPOSMerchantPortal\conf\system</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>-->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>
                    file:D:\workspace\SM\src\main\resources\System.property
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" ref="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>
    <!--<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">-->

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sm.entity" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!--<bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>-->

</beans>
```

And here is my Entity file

```
package com.sm.entity;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by dinesh on 9/5/16.
 */
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    public Long userId;
    @Column(name="name")
    public String name;
    @Column(name="password")
    public String password;
    @Column(name="email")
    public String email;
    @Column(name="phone")
    public String phone;
    @Column(name="mobile")
    public String mobile;
    @Column(name="type")
    public String type;
    @Column(name="status")
    public String status;
    @Column(name="country")
    public String country;
    @Column(name="state")
    public String state;
    @Column(name="city")
    public String city;
    @Column(name="address")
    public String address;

    public User(){}

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

here is Hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.sm.entity.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined User entity bean in the configuration file. You must define it as a bean in the configuration for every entity you are using.

Comment: already i have mentioned that. i have updated my question now see